# How can I solve the problem when using Customtkinter?

Tags: customtkinter

CODE:

import customtkinter

janela = customtkinter.Ctk()
janela.geomtrey("500x600")

problem:

No module named 'customtkinter'

---

**even giving pip install customtkinter and installing it doesn't work

I expected to use Customtkinter, but when I add import customtkinter - 'customtkinter' has a yellow line

Answer (score 0):

This form of code works for me

```
import customtkinter

janela = customtkinter.CTk()
janela.geometry("500x600")
```

you can try these

- pip show customtkinter
- pip install customtkinter --force

or virtual environment